# Resources in JAR not properly resolved within IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, freemarker

I have a freemarker ftl template file which is included for taglibs in an IntelliJ project. The problem is that JspTaglibs is not resolved within IntelliJ. The error highlights the text `JspTaglibs` and the error message is "Cannot resolve variable 'JspTaglibs'". The file contents are as follows:

```
<#assign page=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/taglibs/sitemesh-page.tld"]>
<#assign decorator=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/taglibs/sitemesh-decorator.tld"]>
<#assign security=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/taglibs/security.tld"]>
```

This is an imported Maven project. The included ftl is found within a compiled JAR file that I include as a content root within a Web Module.

Any thoughts on resolving 'JspTaglibs' so that auto-completion and verification can be enabled for Freemarker tags?

Comment: Do you have this JAR file present in the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html)?

Comment: Yes. Other variables are resolved because of it.

Comment: Please file a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: I will, but since I am fairly new to IntelliJ, Maven and Java it may be a while before I get to this.

Comment: The solution was to add the resource folder as a sources directory within the library and not as a content root in the Module. The JAR had always been in the library, included as a dependency, but the specific directory needed to be added as a sources folder.

Comment: Post it as the answer so that others can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the solution was to add the resource folder as a sources directory within the library and not as a content root in the Module. The JAR had always been in the library, included as a dependency, but the specific directory needed to be added as a sources folder.